# After removing Language Support, how to get it back?

Tags: language-support

I've removed Language Support. When I try to install it again, can't find it in software center. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Language Support** application/System Settings item is the command `gnome-language-selector` (located in `/usr/bin/gnome-language-selector`), which is provided by the package `language-selector-gnome`.

To install this package, simply run the command below from a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo apt-get install language-selector-gnome
```

Comment: after finishing the command above, still can't find language support in software center

Comment: just wait for some moments and it is back now :)